# How to pass an object to the value property in option tag using angular?

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a select tag which i have loaded the data through angular ng-repeat.

```
  <select ng-model="user.accessRole">
     <option ng-selected="{{item.name == user.accessRole.name}}"
      ng-repeat="item in accessRoles" value="{{item}}">
         {{item.name}}
     </option>
  </select>
```

Once I submit this the value I got for accessRole model is as below.

```
accessRole:"{"id":1,"name":"admin","accessRights":"administrative access"}"
```

I want this value to be passed without double quotes. That means, 
accessRole:{"id":1,"name":"admin","accessRights":"administrative access"}
I tried out this by removing double quotes in value property.(value={{item}})
But it didn't give me the solution.
How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `JSON.parse()` to convert string to json object

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){

$scope.user = {};
$scope.accessRoles= [{"id":1,"name":"admin","accessRights":"administrative access"}]


$scope.submit = function(){
 console.log($scope.user)
  $scope.user.accessRole = JSON.parse( $scope.user.accessRole)
 console.log($scope.user)
}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 <select ng-model="user.accessRole">
     <option  ng-repeat="item in accessRoles" value="{{item}}">
         {{item.name}}
     </option>
  </select>
  <button ng-click="submit()">click</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. You saved my day :)

Comment: @spcd no problem

Answer (score 2):

It should be like to this.

```js
var app = angular.module('anApp', []);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.user = {};
  $scope.accessRoles= [{"id":1,"name":"admin","accessRights":"administrative access"}];
  
  $scope.display = function(){
    console.log($scope.user);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="anApp" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select ng-options="role as role.name for role in accessRoles" ng-model="user.accessRole" ng-change="display()">
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your answer also corect. But I choose the above since it has been posted first. :)